# How to add a number range of items per page in custom pagination django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have created some serialized data using django rest framework. I am in the process of building a custom pagination, since there is a lot of data that is being serialized. I have managed to add the required key, value pair needed in the custom pagination. The page_size is set to 200.

So it currently displays like this :

```
{
    "totalPages": 11,
    "totalData": 2065,
    "currentPage": 2,
    "nextPage": "http://localhost:8000/cluster/37/tasks?page=3",
    "previousPage": "http://localhost:8000/cluster/37/tasks",
    "results": [...]
}
```

I want to also display additional data in the custom pagination, I want to display the range of the starting data (`firstDataNumber`) and the final data (`lastDataNumber`) in the page. For example in page 1 :

```
{
    "totalPages": 11,
    "totalData": 2065,
    "currentPage": 1,
    "firstDataNumber" : 1, #first data on page
    "lastDataNumber" : 200, #last data on page
...
}
```

same for page 2, which should be :

```
{
    "totalPages": 11,
    "totalData": 2065,
    "currentPage": 2,
    "firstDataNumber" : 201, #first data on page
    "lastDataNumber" : 400, #last data on page
...
}
```

How do I achieve this insertion of a range of data number in the custom pagination? Thanks.

This is my code on custom pagination so far :

```
class LargeResultsSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 200
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 100

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response(OrderedDict([
             ('totalPages', self.page.paginator.num_pages),
             ('totalData', self.page.paginator.count),
             ('currentPage', self.page.number),
             ('nextPage', self.get_next_link()),
             ('previousPage', self.get_previous_link()),
             ('results', data)
         ]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on docs you can access `self.page.start_index()` and `self.page.end_index()`

Docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/paginator/#django.core.paginator.Page.start_index

Comment: Thank you @Kyell! Really it was just a matter of looking over the documentation lol.

Comment: Yes documentation or even the source code if you like. lol